# How to access functionality from two classes on the same hierarchy level?

Tags: objective-c, swift, oop, inheritance

I have a polymorphism-type question (in fact, I'm not entirely sure this is polymorphism, but it sure seems like it.) Below, there is a diagram of four classes –– the base class `UITableViewCell`, two subclasses of that, and a subclass of one of the subclasses.

I need the functionality of both of the two subclasses of `UITableViewCell`, one of which deals with the content view of the cell, while the other handles other actions that can happen ON the cell. One of the subclasses is part of a framework. The `My Cell Class` basically needs to also "inherit" (or whatever technical word instead of that) the functionality of `Cell Subclass A` and `Cell Subclass B`. A + B are Objective-C subclasses; A is ported to Swift through the module availability file built into the framework; B is through the bridging header. I'm using Swift. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Diagram of class hierarchy]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot *inherit* from more than one class in Swift. When you see notation such as `class AnotherSwiftClass: MyFirstProtocol, AnotherProtocol {}` the second parameter is actually a *protocol*. You can access the functionality of the protocol, however. Here's a [good source](https://www.weheartswift.com/swift-classes-part-2/) on how to use inheritance and protocols.

Comment: Right, I'm in complete agreement and understanding with your answer. I'm really looking for a roundabout way to access the functionality of both classes. None of them are protocols...

Comment: I'm not sure you want to do that. They designed inheritance like this for a reason. My suggestion would be to build a protocol and populate it as a wrapper for the functionality of Subclass A. Where each method gets an entry or etc. Or you could convert the methods in subclass A to class methods. If it's not too much work, my best suggestion is to just rewrite any methods in subclass A fro subclass B, though I have no idea how different these classes are.